# How can I automate a mass edit of text files located in a Win 8.1 directory?

Tags: batch-file, web, powershell-3.0

Good day,

in a specific directory under Win 8.1, I have these hundreds of text files with the extension *.xml, representing a Web site.

In each and every of those files there is exactly one occurence of a certain tag with a known content, say `<tag>old</tag>`.

In all these pages, this specific text needs to be replaced by `<tag>new</tag>`. Subdirectories exist, but they do not need to be examined.

How would I automate this task? (I am not familiar with the PowerShell, don't think I've ever used it, but would that be heading into the right direction? If not - apologies for the misleading tag.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PowerShell could be used to do this, without much difficulty, but I'm fairly sure that there are implementations of the *ix utility `sed` available for Windows, and although I'm not intimately familiar with the *ix shell, I'm pretty sure that this would be trivial with `sed`.

Comment: I had a look into its syntax, and yes, it's quite *ixish ;) In the end, I went with JoeH's answer, simply because it can be done with on-board means. Thanks anyway, Jeff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this PowerShell script.

```
$myFiles=get-childitem C:\Folder *.xml -rec
foreach ($file in $myFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "<tag>old</tag>", "<tag>new</tag>"} | 
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Comment: This. Works like a charm, and is quite performant, too. Well earned reputation, Sir, and welcome.

Comment: Indeed. Quite elegant, and reminds me once again that when working with PowerShell, some of my preconceptions are wrong (my pure-PS solution would have involved some machinations to avoid appearing to overwrite the source file while I appeared to be still processing it...).

Comment: As a side note, you could have avoided the use of `$myFiles` by simply writing the loop header as `foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem C:\Folder *.xml -rec))`

Comment: Besides Jeff's rationalisation, which is true: also, of course, the body's Foreach-Object implies, that *every* occurence of "<tag>old</tag>" would be catched (and substituted). Although the performace is good, I wonder, what one could do to catch just the first (= only) occurence.

Answer (score 0):

check [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
for %%# in (*.xml) do (
   call replacer.bat "%%~f#" "<tag>old</tag>" "<tag>new</tag>"
)
```